# What does CRON=1 do?

Tags: cron, environment-variables

What does setting CRON=1 do when set in front of a command?

```
CRON=1 ./foobar.sh
```

I suspect that the cron environment variable does something for printing to standard out. But I can't find anything in the man pages, or google.

**Update**

To clarify, I'm specifically wondering what the CRON environment variable does.

Comment: Depends on what the program `./foobar.sh` does with environment variable `CRON`.

Comment: Note: There is no need to put a `.sh` at end of scripts filesname. As it is if you change implementation to python, then you would have to change file-name, the name is leaking implementation detail.

Comment: @richard if you completely re-write a script you probably will just make a new file for it anyways. Plus you have to be able to read a file in order to execute it so people are still going to know whether it's a bash or python script.

Comment: @Bratchley yes you do rewrite it. But do you want to edit every other script that uses your script, just because the file-name changed.

Comment: It's possible that's pretty marginal work (moving to the new command name) but I see your point.

Comment: @Bratchley - just to be nit picky ;) - What if there are scripts, etc. which are on unmounted media that you can't get to, or scripts you don't have write permission for? Then, a new name could involve a lot of possible consequences with very little upside. I know I get too used to having root/sudo permissions on my machine - so I can do anything - and then assume somewhat unjustified omnipotence.

Comment: @Joe anything that elaborate would probably be going through change control which addresses those concerns and more. People would be advised what the new script name is and be given a timeline to complete migrating their code over. If it's just one admin's script then it's still possibly a change control item but the admin will usually have some means of updating other code and since they've already just re-written a supposedly non-trivial bash script into python this wouldn't be all that much more work.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a variable on the command line immediately before a command. Doing so will set that variable in the command's environment.

To see the effect of setting the variable in the script's environment, you will need to consult the script itself, and possibly the commands *used by* the script. The `CRON` environment variable is not special or standard and has no particular meaning for the `cron` daemon or the shell.